# sum of increasing and decreasing function has at most one maximum

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f(x) \geq 0$ and $g(x) \geq 0$, both be strictly increasing and concave functions in $x>0$.

Can we show that $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) $ has *at most* one mode (i.e., global maximum) by the first assumptions?

Update: I added the condition on concavity for $f$ and $g$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if $f=g$? Both are strictly increasing.In particular $f=g=x$.

Comment: Don't change your question significantly after receiving answers (here: adding the concavity condition). That invalidates the given answers and confuses future readers of this Q&A. Better ask a new question.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for letting me know. I added the update-phrase at the end of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is untrue. Let $f(x)=x+\sin x+1$, $g(x)=x$. Both functions are increasing, but $h(x)=\sin x+1$ has infinitely many global maxima.

As noted in the comments, there is an even simpler counter-example: $f(x)=g(x)=x$.

Comment: Then even if both functions are strictly increasing and concave, we cannot conclude that, right?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinEshraghi That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

"What if $f=g$? Both are strictly increasing.In particular $f=g=x$."

As I said in the comments $f=g$ is a sort of trivial example.

If you want a non trivial one , let $f=x+1,g=x$.

---

Why am I even writing an answer? Someone already answered, may be because of reputation points. Sorry, if I sound greedy. Its 3:45AM here , I should sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:

[image]

Comment: Thanks David, but the blue function is not concave. Could you come up with a concave counter-example?

Comment: The blue is concave:  Take a point on each "bump," draw a straight line between them to see that the line passes above the function.